# How to set aaptOptions in Xamarin.Android for TensorFlow Lite .tflite File

Tags: xamarin.android, tensorflow2.0, aapt, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to work on the tflite stuffs and try to open the tflite file but got error. From internet, it seems everybody is talking about adding the below setting in Android Studio at the build.gradle file.

```
android {
    // ...
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'tflite'
    }
}
```

But since I am doing it in Xamarin.Android and without gradle file, anybody now where and how can I set this in Xamarin?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this will work for you, but this might be it:

In Visual Studio, open the Android project properties > "Android Options". There's a box that says "Leave the following resource extensions uncompressed", with examples `.dll;.mp3`.

So you might try putting `.tflite` there.

Comment: Yeah I actually managed to did it a couple of days before, it works. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: I was struggling with the same thing for a different reason, and it hasn't been documented elsewhere. So hopefully this will help other people :-)